# Sphero API Calibration

Tags: sphero-api, sphero

PROBLEM: SetHeading API doesn't calibrate Sphero.

I am building a small little custom app with Sphero and would like to implement a configuration UI.  However, I am not using the RobotLibrary but instead making Sphero API calls.

When implementing the Sphero calibration steps:

1. I turn on the back led.
2. I issue the SetHeading command with the heading data, but the device doesn't not adjust.

   Alternatively, I can send the Roll command with a velocity of zero and the heading data and the device does adjust in place. However, after calibration is over, when I attempt to "Roll" the device, the device with adjust back to original calibration and then move.

CONCLUSION: It seems that Roll command with a zero velocity is not the correct way to calibration the Sphero but SetHeading doesn't do anything.  I have tried the SetHeading with SetStabilization on and off.  Neither effects SetHeading and aids the calibration.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Roll command with zero velocity to 'aim' the robot.  As you noted, lighting the back led is helpful.  Once done aiming, call SetHeading with 0 degrees heading parameter.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bit tricky to get it to work properly, here is the snippet I am using:

```
sphero.roll(0, heading, 2, ()=> {
    setTimeout(()=> {
        sphero.setHeading(0, ()=> {
           sphero.roll(0, 0, 1, ()=> {
               //done
           });
        });
    }, 300);
});
```